# SELECT столбца из TEMPORARY table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Пытаюсь выполнить такой запрос:

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmporient
ON COMMIT DROP
AS 
SELECT * FROM orient_parameters
WITH NO DATA;
COPY tmporient FROM 'D:/downloads/BOKZ1.txt' DELIMITER '    ';
SELECT * FROM tmporient LIMIT 1;
SELECT tmporient.DateTime FROM tmporient;
INSERT INTO orient_parameters SELECT DISTINCT ON (tmporient.KA_num,tmporient.DateTime,tmporient.Time_pr)* FROM tmporient;
COMMIT;
```

Запрос по всем столбцам выполняется:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А при попытке выбрать отдельный выдается ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы в PostgreSQL у имени поля учитывался регистр букв, нужно брать имя в двойные кавычки:

```
SELECT "DateTime" FROM tmporient;
```

Вы указали без кавычек - соответственно, была попытка найти поле `datetime`, которого, как и написано в тексте ошибки, не существует.